# Define $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$ so they satisfy equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Define $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, if
$$\overline{abc}+\frac{\overline{abc}}{2^2}+\frac{\overline{abc}}{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{\overline{abc}}{2^n} = 2^n + 2^{n-1} - 1$$

I'm a bit confused about the first bit, as it doesn't fit the pattern for a series, I tried to work with the rest, but no luck.

Comment: What should $\overline{abc}$ mean?

Comment: $\overline{abc}$ means a number with digits $a,b,c$

Comment: Are you sure the term $\frac{\overline{ABC}}{2^1}$ is supposed to be missing from the left side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that the LHS isn't a geometric series, but it's *very close* to one. Indeed, $$\overline{abc}+\frac{\overline{abc}}{2^2}+\frac{\overline{abc}}{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{\overline{abc}}{2^n}=\bigg(\overline{abc}+\frac{\overline{abc}}{2^1}+\frac{\overline{abc}}{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{\overline{abc}}{2^n}\bigg)-\frac{\overline{abc}}{2^1}$$Using the geometric series formula, this is equal to $$\overline{abc}\cdot\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}-1}{\frac{1}{2}-1}-\frac{\overline{abc}}{2^1}=\overline{abc}\cdot\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2^n}-\overline{abc}\cdot\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n}=\overline{abc}\cdot\frac{2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}-1}{2^n}$$Now since $2^{n+1}=4\cdot 2^{n-1}$ and $2^{n}=2\cdot 2^{n-1}$, we know $$2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}-1=2^{n}+2^{n-1}-1,$$so our original equation becomes $$\overline{abc}\cdot\frac{2^{n}+2^{n-1}-1}{2^n}=2^n+2^{n-1}-1$$or $$\overline{abc}=2^n$$So we want to find all powers of $2$ that have $3$ digits; these are $\overline{abc}=128,256,512$, which correspond to $n=7,8,9$.